# Applying the Intermediate Value Theorem on periodic functions

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have just recently covered the Intermediate Value Theorem, and I wanted to practice solving problems involving this theorem. However, I encountered a problem that I am not exactly sure how to tackle (it's a question involving a periodic function). 
I thought about splitting the proofs into 3 cases, but I don't think it would be applicable here?

> The question is:
>
> If $f$ is periodic with a period of $2a$ for some $a>0$, then $f(x)=f(x+2a)$ for all $x∈R$. Show that if $f$ is continous, there exists some $c∈[0,a]$ such that $f(c)=f(c+a)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Good question! Try the function $g(x)=f(x+a)-f(x)$ since the sum/difference of continuous functions is continuous, $g$ is continuous. If you still can't get it, leave a comment for me.
**note this may not work, but on first look I am pretty sure it will**

Comment: Yep. Note that $g(0)=-g(a)$ and you are good to go!

Comment: Thanks! I will try to tinker with the question and post my results here.

Answer (score 2):

I will post my solution here, but do try writing it out on your own first.

Set $g(x) = f(x+a)-f(x)$.

Then we see that $g(0)=f(a)-f(0)$ and $g(a)=f(2a)-f(a)=f(0)-f(a)$. We see that $g(a)=-g(0)$.

Therefore, since $g$ is a sum of continuous functions, it must be continuous in its domain too. By applying intermediate value theorem, we see that $0$ is between $g(a)$ and $g(0)$, and thus there exists some $c\in[0,a]$ such that $g(c)=f(a+c)-f(c)=0$. (i.e. $f(c)=f(c+a)$)